# How to test the class method which use construct variable

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

#### Game.php

```
<?php

class Game
{
    public $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new DB;
    }

    public function result()
    {
        return $this->db->data();
    }
}
```

#### DB.php

```
<?php

class DB
{
    public function data()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### GameTest.php

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;

class GameTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testResult()
    {
        $game = m::mock(new Game);
        $game->shouldReceive('data')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);
        $expected = $game->result();

        $this->assertTrue($expected);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }
}
```

This is my solution but totally not work, I guess if I want to get setting from `__construct` I need to mock a new class, I got message `Failed asserting that false is true.` which mean the mock thing is not work, how to deal with it?

Comment: Never used Mockery before but it looks like you have a Game object mock here, and are mocking the Db object's methods in it?

Comment: Yes, normally we will use dependency Injection, but I am trying every possibility to use Mockery

Comment: data() isn't a method though of the Game object. From what I understand, shouldReceive() accepts a method name that exists inside your mocked object

Comment: true, https://hackmd.io/s/4yq_hHhA, this is how I mock internal method, I just try to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, best solution would be to use dependency injection for $db.
That way you can mock only DB like this...

```
$dbMock = m::mock('DB');
$dbMock->shouldReceive('data')
      ->once()
      ->andReturn(true);
```

Or you can keep you constructor like this (without DI), but you will have to mock that constructor also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockery by creating an "instance mock" for the DB class like this:

```
$dbMock = Mockery::mock('overload:MyNamespace\DB');
```

This will "intercept" when a new instance of the DB class is created and the $dbMock will be used instead. When the `$dbMock` is created you just need to add an expectation declaration for the given method:

```
$dbMock->shouldReceive('data')
  ->once()
  ->andReturn(true);
```